# Better way to destruction items in array? Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need better way to create arrays

Check my code:

```
  const [first, second, third, four, ...others] = allItems;
 
  return (
    <div >
      {[first, second, third, four].map().
   </div> 
   )
```

I am using react but that is not important here.

I need to better a way to get first four item.

WHat is allItems?

This is array of object.

Comment: You're going to need some more information here. What are `first`, `second`, (etc), `others`, and `allItems`? Why do you need a better way What's wrong with what you have?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

> The `slice()` method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array
> into a new array object selected from start to end (end not included)
> where start and end represent the index of items in that array. The
> original array will not be modified.

For example:

```
allItems.slice(0,4)
```

(And `allItems.slice(4)` for the others)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is `allItems.slice(0,4)`.

```
  return (
    <div >
      {allItems.slice(0,4).map()}.
   </div> 
   )
```

Comment: Nice but how to know others ?